# issue with setAttribute into a servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I try to pass attributes to a request into a servlet, but somehow it does not seem to work:

```
try{
        request.setAttribute("str","test");
        request.setAttribute("compt",compt);
        request.setAttribute("raton",raton); //I tried with different types

// request.getParameterMap().size() always evaluate to 0 instead of "the number of arguments"

Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap(); 
        for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) { //is never looped

                String[] values = parameters.get(parameter);

                for(String v : values) out.println(v);

        }



        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And of course consequently, I get no attribute when parsing the request into the JSP.
Did I miss something??

Thx in advance

Edit: I did not post the JSP asthe issue is scoped before even redirecting, but here it is:

```
<body>
<%PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
%>
visites : 
<%
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
    //this is never looped , nothing is displyed
        String[] values = parameters.get(parameter);

        for(String v : values) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }

}

 %>
</body>
```

Comment: Show us your JSP too.

Comment: You're setting attributes, and reading parameters. These are very different things. Read the attributes using getAttribute(), and you'll find them. You also didn't post your JSP, so we can't explain why it doesn't do what you expect to do (which you haven't said, BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are the data sent by the browser when sending a request such as

```
http://localhost/foo?a=1&b=2
```

In the above example, the request has two parameters, "a" and "b", whose values are "1" and "2". Parameters are always strings.

Attributes are completely different things. They're objects, of any type you want, that the server chooses to store in the request, in order for another server-side component (a JSP, for example) to get them later.

To get an attribute, you don't use getParameterMap(). That returns parameters. You use [getAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-).

From a JSP you can simply use

```
${str}
```

to get and print the attribute named `"str"`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarification between parameters and attributes, I figured out that I can display my attribute the following ways, as per your advice:

```
-1-
${raton}
-2-
<% out.println(request.getAttribute("raton"));    %>
-3-<%=request.getAttribute("raton") %>
```